# Cannot open ASP.NET MVC 3 solution's test project in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, monodevelop

If I create an ASP.NET MVC 3 (with Razor) application in Visual Studio 2010, and have it also create an associated test project, I am not able to open the test project in MonoDevelop.

I have the latest version of MonoDevelop (2.6 beta 1) installed, with Mono Framework 2.10.1, running on OS X.

When I open the solution, I get the following error in MonoDevelop:

> "Could not load project '/Users/apps/Code/C#/MvcApplication2/MvcApplication2.Tests/MvcApplication2.Tests.csproj' with unknown item type '{3AC096D0-A1C2-E1C2-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}'"

The project "MvcApplication2.Test" then shows as (Load failed) under the solution explorer.

Is there something that I can do to get this project to load? Or is this project type not supported by MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's normal. When you create a new Test Project in Visual Studio by default it uses Microsoft Test Framework, meaning that the only support you could open it is Visual Studio which has the necessary assemblies installed. To make this work on Mono you will need to use some other testing framework such as NUnit for example.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, Microsoft Test is not supported by MonoDevelop.